# Seeking QGIS Tile / Basemap Options

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, satellite

We have been using QGIS to collect and produce maps for fiber optic deployment to areas where there is no fiber.  We use OpenStreetMap as the base tile map, for streets and building structures.  We also use BING and Google for satellite.

Are there any other options besides or in addition to OSM?

Some of the challenges we have found
When we zoom in OSM, the building address number can get blurry, zoom out get to small.

Is there a source (free or paid) that would overlay property lines and address info like in shape file?

On the satellite views, we have seem in other systems, like when we work with Frontier, the satellite imagery is much better and clear especially when you zoom in.  I'm sure they pay for it but wanted to ask.

[image]

Comment: Maybe look into the QuickMapService plugin? It has a range of basemaps. Not sure you'll find the exact one you are looking for. Depending on your location, there may be a geoportal with local property data.

Comment: I tried that nothing better than OSM

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

As standard OpenStreetMap tiles only zooms up to zoom 19, which roughly relates to a scale of 1:1000, you get a blurry display by overzooming in 1:624 (your screenshot).

So you should use tiles that a) go higher in zoom and b) best use retina tiles with a higher dpi. E.g. these tiles here: https://www.maptilesapi.com/retina-tiles/ go up to zoom 20 (1:500) plus use a higher dpi (so as a xyz layer you would choose "Tile Resolution High"). Then your basemap would look a lot less blurry.

Example:

[image]

Comment: This looks Awesome, I signed up on their website, to sort of take a test drive with Free account, trying to find doc on how to integrate into QGIS?  Been playing around for about half hour, tried adding as a new tile - https://retina-tiles.p.rapidapi.com/local/osm{r}/v1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?rapidapi-key=YOUR-RAPIDAPI-KEY

Comment: Hi, you'll need the following URL: "https://retina-tiles.p.rapidapi.com/local/osm@2x/v1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?rapidapi-key=YOUR-RAPIDAPI-KEY" and set the tile resolution to High. QGIS cannot substitute the {r} parameter in the URL; that's why you have to explicitly set it yourself. More information can be found here: https://rapidapi.com/MapTilesApi/api/retina-tiles/tutorials/using-high-resolution-openstreetmap-retina-tiles-in-qgis

Comment: Thanks again, this was perfect, really appreciate the assist.