# Label size in OSM tiles

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, tiles, user-interface

I'm just curious if someone can display OSM with larger labels in QGIS. I know tiles are built on the server, and this is likely a showstopper. The layer source is [https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

This place is the [Musée du Louvre](https://www.google.com/maps/@48.8600147,2.3372876,17z) in Paris: Labels are unusable, they should be similar to the QGIS menu bar labels:

[image]

Zooming doesn't improve anything (except when beyond the highest zoom level and pixels start to be enlarged, including labels).

[image]

In comparison, Google Maps:

[image]

I wouldn't say it's better, for other reasons, but at least labels can be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you using a raster tile source, you would need a source with retina tiles, e.g. by following this guide: https://rapidapi.com/MapTilesApi/api/retina-tiles/tutorials/using-high-resolution-openstreetmap-retina-tiles-in-qgis.

You may also have a look at this question and answers here:

[Seeking QGIS Tile / Basemap Options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428156/seeking-qgis-tile-basemap-options/)

Example:

[image: larger text in qgis with raster retina tiles]

Do the following: choose the retina tiles url as described in the linked tutorial above but use 96dpi (256px*256px) as tile size in your XYZ tiles layer.

Then use the magnifier (e.g. I used 200%) and you get a readable example (it would be nearly unreadable/blurry if you use normal osm tiles). Please note: I had to scale down the screenshot for file size to have it inserted here/at imgur - please click the image to get a better representation).

Comment: Can you explain how it improves the labels on a computer without a retina display (my case).  Perhaps a screenshot? On the linked question, it's a matter of zoom blurring past 19, but for OSM the problem is not this one, as when I zoom (see the question), the label size is reduced by the server. I'd be happy if the server wasn't continuously reducing the size.

Comment: Hi mins, I've updated the answer with a (scaled down) screenshot and and explanation on how I used those tiles for larger text labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful. These tiles are really an improvement.